# Test iphone apps in ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, testing

i want buy iphone or ipad any one for testing iphone and ipad applications.my doubt is if i test a iphone applications in ipad?, my choice want to buy ipad but,if i am testing iphone apps in ipad is possible? because,i am not using ipad can any one help me for decide correct decision with greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can test iPhone applications on iPad, the application will zoom to 2X to fill the iPad screen, so if you need to test on both iPhone and iPad, buying an iPad is a good choice

Comment: iPhone5 (and now iPhone 6,6+) apps don't run well on iPad. They uses the 320x480 scale, hence iPhone5 supported apps doesn't run goo.

Comment: What should we do to make an iPhone5 app running on iPad app?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this but to test iPhone app on iPad it must be iPhone-only app. Then you will be able to use the zoom capability (which doesnt look nice btw). If you create universal app (which you should do) and test it on iPad it will switch to iPad views and you will end up with iPhone views untested. You can try to manipulate the project settings to make your universal app use the iPhone views on iPad for testing but this isn't the most convenient way to work. 
Anyway, if you can't afford two devices right now buy iPad first, create your app, submit it to App Store, make money and buy an iPhone. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what Adam answered:

You can test iPhone apps on the iPad, but there are some differences. For example, the iPhone has two speakers rather than one so you must specifically reroute the audio to the speaker. Also, you can't replicate application interruptions (such as a phone call or sms text) as easily. Another - iAds that are for iPhone applications don't load on the iPad.

These are only the problems I ran into, and with some thinking you can spread your debugging across the simulator and the iPad to solve most problems. But there are some problems you may run into.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, buying an ipad is better because you can test your iphone app in ipad as well but an ipad app/universal app can't be tested in iphone.

Comment: Universal apps can (and should be) tested on an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

iPad can run most of the iPhone (iPod touch) applications. After installing the iPhone SDK 3.2 open your iPhone simulator and select below from the menu

Hardware –> Versions –> 3.2

This will open your iPhone application in iPad simulator. By default the app will be open on the center of the iPad screen with ugly black border. :P but the application will zoom to 2X to fill the iPad screen.. so iPad is best..